# Excel Auto Populate Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know how I can make Excel auto copy a specific cell into a predetermined part of a sentence.

Hopefully this will help explain the issue.
I have three cells, with a number in each:

```
|  $588.40|  $400.60|  $375.60|
```

I have the sentence template

> ***Max Tend to account INC DEL$ XXX DEL $XXX Cust to pay $xxx Issue client tax invoice ***

I want Excel to auto populate the $XXX to read:

> ***Max Tend to account INC DEL$400.60 DEL $375.60 Cust to pay $588.40 Issue client tax invoice ***

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the cells holding the values to be populated are A1,B1 and C1, respectively. The following formula returns the desired result:

```
="***Max Tend to account INC DEL"&B1&"DEL "&C1&" Cust to pay "&A1&" Issue client tax invoice *"
```